# JQuery-JTable plugin with CI don't show the data and amount of rows more than Total Record Count

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jtable

I used CI and JTable plugin but I got problem. The result didn't shown in the table and number of rows more than total record count..... 
Here is my code. This link directs you to my code in folder View 
View : http://pastebin.com/iXB9i0BW

Controller :

```
function listRecord()
{
    $this->load->model('penyusutan_action');
    $jTableResult=$this->penyusutan_action->list_record();
    print_r(json_encode($jTableResult));
    exit();

}
```

Model :

```
function list_record()
{

    $result = mysql_query("select * FROM daftar_inventory where tgl_perolehan <= '$tgl' and GL_induk between '$GL_awal' and '$GL_akhir' ; ");
    $recordCount = mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$rows[] = $row;
}

$jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    $jTableResult['TotalRecordCount'] = $recordCount;
    $jTableResult['Records'] = $rows;
    return $jTableResult;
}
```

I was Checking the responses in my browser. Here is the result

```
{"Result":"OK", "TotalRecordCount":1, "Records":{...,...,.....}
```

But the number of rows is 8 and it shows an empty data. Here is the picture of the table. 
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1008375815846277&set=a.231153066901893.81420.100000216048594&type=1&theater 
Anyone got the same problems or know how to solve it? help me please ....... Thanks.

Comment: Have you check your browser's console? I mean firebug or something?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't see a trouble

Comment: Have you checked listAction url does it work properly? I think you need to use <?php echo base_url(); ?>

Comment: No. that is not the problem. because I got its responses.

Comment: Try to change $rows[] = $row; for $rows = $row; ?

Comment: @Altrazar thanks. I just try your idea. But I code like this.
$rows = array(); 

$rows[] = [
 'id_Aset'=>$row['id_Aset'],
 'tanggal' => $tahun.'-'.$bulan.'-01',
 'GL' => $row['GL'],
 'nama_item'=>$row['nama_item'],
 'id_cabang'=>$row['id_cabang'],
 'masa_susut'=>$total_bulan,
 'total_penyusutan'=>$total_penyusutan,
 'saldo'=>$saldo];
And the problem is solved. Thanks... :D :D